# Firebase app check with Play integrity not returning token giving 403 error GeneratePlayIntegrityChallenge are blocked

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I have integrated the firebase app check in my android project and followed all the requisites that are mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider#project-setup).
Additional to this I have also added the setUp code

```
        val firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()
        val factory = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
        } else {
            PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
        }
        firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(factory)
```

Also the code below to fetch the token

```
            .getAppCheckToken(false)
            .addOnSuccessListener {token->
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            }
```

I am running it in debug app and have added all the debug token to my console by following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/debug-provider#emulator).

But the problem is I am always getting an exception like this

```
Error returned from API. code: 403 body: Requests to this API firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com method google.firebase.appcheck.v1.TokenExchangeService.ExchangeDebugToken are blocked.
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have crossed checked all the Ids and SHA-fingerprints that I have added to firebase console and they are all correct.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that internally App Check uses an android key for token generation. You can find this Android key in your google cloud console  [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) .
Make sure that this key is not restricted and that you have allowed Firebase App Check API for that key. If you have not allowed this you will get the `google.firebase.appcheck.v1.TokenExchangeService.ExchangeDebugToken are blocked`.

[image: Credentials view for google cloud console]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1--> First set up "App Check" in Firebase console for Auth, Firestore, Storage etc

2--> Add "firebase_app_check" package in your flutter project.

3--> Add the below code in "main.dart" in main method.

```
    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(options: 
      DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

      FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.instance;
      firebaseAppCheck.activate(androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug);
      firebaseAppCheck.getToken();
      }
```

4--> After then restart your project and you will see following token on console.

```
     Enter this debug secret into the allow list in the Firebase Console 
     for your project: ********-****-****-****-************
```

5--> Copy this token and add it in Firebase console-> Appcheck -> Apps -> Three dots -> add debug token.